# Page isn't working in php

Tags: php

I am out of ideas with a php/html problem.

Why would this php code cause an *"Page localhost isn't working. Localhost didn't sent any data."* error? No php error displayed or logged.

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 25202; $i++) echo $i;
?>
```

If I limit the $i variable to 25201 everything works fine. I don't know what cause this error in browser, because if I run my php script from command line there is no problem even if I set the $i limit to 5000000.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Turn on error reporting and you might some more details as to why it isn't working.

Comment: check for script execution time limit max_execution_time in php.ini . Try increasing it , restart the web server and see if it makes any difference

Comment: The PHP CLI has no max execution time whereas PHP run in the web server does. That seems like the first thing you should check `max_execution_time = 60` by default I think it is set to 30 seconds

Comment: `max_execution_time=60`
Please look at the script, it can not take longer than 1-2 seconds.

Comment: Check the webserver logs

Comment: There is no error in webserver logs, no php error, nothing.
I think there is something about the limit if the amount of data sent to the browser, or something about the memory used by php. But on the same server I have more complex scripts that sends a lot of data to the browser.

Comment: Maybe your browser can not handle amount of numbers; try reducing it I mean `echo ($i % 2) ? $i : '';`